# Reverse characters word in array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

for exemple i need to invers "Paris" to "siraP"...

My main:

```
int main(void)
{
    char w1[] = "Paris";
    ReverseWord(w1);
    printf("The new word is: %s",w1);
    return0;
}
```

and my function:

```
void ReverseWord(char *Str)
{
     int counter=0;
     for(int i=0; *(Str+i)!='\0'; i++)
          counter++;

     int length = counter-1;

     char temp[length];

     for(int j=0; temp[j]=='\0'; j++)
          temp[j]=Str[length-j];
}
```

Now I have my renverse word in temp[].
I need to put it in my pointer *Str.
How can I do it??

Thanks

Comment: Note that you don't need to use temporary storage for this, you can swap characters instead.

Comment: Also, your loop is not correct: you check `temp[j]` before assigning it. Condition should be `j < length`

Comment: if it is windows u can use strrev()

Comment: you cant do char temp[length]

Comment: `char temp[length];` not initialized by 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want use `temp` must then your function like this

```
void ReverseWord(char *Str)
{
    int i,j;

    if(str)
    {
      int length=strlen(Str);
      char temp[length+1];

      for( j=0; j<length; j++)
          temp[j]=Str[length-1-j];

      temp[j]='\0';

      strcpy(Str,temp);
   }

}
```

Without using `temp` as follows

```
void ReverseWord(char *Str)
{
    int end= strlen(Str)-1;
    int start = 0;

    while( start<end )
    {
        Str[start] ^= Str[end];
        Str[end] ^= Str[start];
        Str[start]^= Str[end];

        ++start;
        --end;
    }
}
```

Comment: `char temp[length+1];`!

Answer (score 1):

```
void ReverseWord(char *Str)
{
    size_t len;
    char temp, *end;

    len = strlen(Str);
    if (len < 2)
        return;

    end = Str + len - 1;
    while (end > Str)
    {
        temp = *end;
        *end-- = *Str;
        *Str++ = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option, this time with dangerous malloc(3).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *rev(char s[]) {
  char *buf = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(s));
  int i, j;

  if(buf != NULL)
    for(i = 0, j = strlen(s) - 1; j >= 0; i++, j--)
      buf[i] = s[j];

  return buf;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("%s\n", rev(argv[1]));
  return 0;
}
```

Run with `"foo bar foobar baz"` and get `zab raboof rab oof` back:

```
~/tmp$ ./a.out "foo bar foobar baz"
zab raboof rab oof
```

Comment: Why is malloc dangerous ??

Comment: Well, bad joke. It's not dangerous in itself, only when not used correctly. For example in this case one should use strnlen() instead of strlen() to make sure malloc() doesn't get anything ridiculous as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here I think you can study two algorithms:

1. C string length calculate: the end of the c string is '\0'
2. How to reverse a c string in place

And if you need to test the code, you should alloc testing strings in heap or strack. If you write a literal string, you may meet a **bus error** because of the literal string being saved in text-area which is a read only memory.

And the following is the demo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void reverse_string(char* str)
{
    size_t len;
    char tmp, *s;
    //Get the length of string, in C the last char of one string is \0
    for(s=str;*s;++s) ;
    len = s - str;

    //Here we use the algorithm for reverse the char inplace.
    //We only need a char tmp place for swap each char
    s = str + len - 1;
    while(s>str){
        tmp = *s;
        *s = *str;
        *str = tmp;
        s--;
        str++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char* a = "abcd";
    //Here "abcd" will be saved in READ Only Memory. If you test code, you will get a bus error.
    char* b = (char*)calloc(1,10);
    strcpy(b,a);
    reverse_string(b);
    printf("%s\n",b);

    a = "abcde";
    strcpy(b,a);
    reverse_string(b);
    printf("%s\n",b);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do it simply by following code

```
for(int k=0;k<strlen(temp);k++)
     {
        Str[k]=temp[k];
     }
```

Comment: You just reinvented a inefficient version of strcpy. That doesn't even copy the terminating 0.

Comment: No, read the the question. And your method is still inefficient and wrong.

Comment: i dont find my code inefficient.i wonder why are you saying so?

Comment: It's inefficient, because strlen is evaluated every time in the loop. You only need to evaluate it once, because the length of the string doesn't change. So you should write `int len = strlen(temp) ; for(int k = 0; k <= len; k++) {Str[k]=temp[k];}` or even better : `char *src = temp ; while (*Str++ = *temp++) {} ;`

Comment: you cannot do char *src = temp as temp is local to the called function and *src holds the address of array in main.then changing the address it holds is very bad practice

Comment: It doesn't change any address. After the `char *src = temp` statement src points the 1st element of the temp array. Then `while (*Str++ = *temp++) {}` just copies the content of the temp buffer to the Src buffer and that's exactly what we want. Try it yourself.

Comment: yes i know that it will work but it is dangerous in big problems because when the function is executed its local variables are destroyed and now when temp is destroyed when the function is finished then to which entity Src will point as operating system will take the allocated address back?so it is dangerous my friend.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49157/discussion-between-michael-walz-and-bayant-singh)